# how to merging works with git

Tags: git, merge

let say I have a project

```
project
---index.php
---css
-------main.css
---js
-------main.js
```

I and my another two friends fetch the project
Then I code a module:

```
project
---css
------modules_a.css
---js
------javascript_a.js
---modules
------modules_a.php
```

and my teamcode code:

```
project
---css
------modules_b.css
---js
------javascript_b.js
---modules
------modules_b.php
```

and my another teamcode code:

```
project
---css
------modules_c.css
---js
------javascript_c.js
---modules
------modules_c.php
```

---

What three of us should command (in git) to merge all off our code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those are three separate sets of files, there shouldn't be any conflict.

You can pull the work of your colleagues directly (by adding their repos as remote to your own repo if you have a network access to their repos): pick one [publishing workflow](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html).

Or you can setup a centralized repo (either through your LAN if you have all access to the same internal network, or through the WAN, like a public GitHub repo): it depends [on the server you have access to](http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html).

Comment: if I use shared repository, so three of us just 'git push' and that will combine all...I fear that last push delete previous file in shared repo

Comment: @Arief: for separate sets of files, the three push won't delete or cancel any previous work. Only add what the respective push brings to the common repo.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Chapter 4 of the git User's Guide](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#sharing-development). It covers the various options for sharing development with others.

I'd look into a repository host (e.g. [github](https://github.com/)). If you want to do it yourself, check out the [public repository section in the git maual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#public-repositories)